# Opções de login são pequenas e fazem o layout quebrar

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design, layout

A imagem explica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A última opção ("Stack Exchange") está grande demais e não cabe no seu container. Minha sugestão é o deixar mais largo:

```
.preferred-login {
    width: 300px;
}
#forgot-password {
    margin-left: 330px;
}
```

Comment: Acho que o esqueci a senha deveria ser embaixo do log-in do stack exchange também, não?

Comment: Acho que o "esqueci a senha" deve ficar onde está, pois ele se refere apenas à opção de login usado o Stack Exchange, ele não serve para recuperar a senha do seu Facebook nem do Google. Se ele for para baixo pode ficar ambíguo.